# Dialog in ViewPager while onClick

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-alertdialog

I got this problem where I want a button to be clickable and show some info in AlertDialog with "OK" button user can dismiss it. I have no errors - simply nothing happens after touching the button.

Here's the instantiateItem code:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    // Declare Variables
    final ImageView imggun;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);

    Button btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Dialog title");
                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Dialog content text...");
                dialogBuilder.create();

        }
    });


    return itemView;
}
```

Looks like it's all good, but nothing happens :/

Comment: You probably want to also show the `AlertDialog`, `dialogBuilder.create().show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show a dialog, you have to call show() method on AlertDialog. That's why you don't see anything. At the end, when you call dialogBuilder.create(), you create an AlertDialog.

```
AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Here's the android documentation about it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show()